# Find ddos attack on OpenVZ container

Tags: linux, virtualization, vps, virtual-machines, openvz

How do you figure out which OpenVZ contain is under attack from a dDoS?

I know it is an attack because the b/w and incoming traffic shot WAY up.

Can this be done with netstat? Are some attacks not going to show up on netstat like UDP if they hit a port with no service running? Is there a monitoring service I could maybe install on the host node?

Comment: What makes you think any of them are under attack?

Comment: Big increase of incoming traffic on the host node on the B/W charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run tcpdump on the host machine for a while and then analyze the captured packets. The IP that shows up most frequently is likely the target of the attack.